# R gt_summary package Getting the SD of the maximum

Tags: gtsummary

I am trying to get the sd of the maximum for different participants using the gt_summary package.

I have tried to use the following code to get the mean, sd and max. However, apart from mean, sd and max, I am also interested in getting the standard deviation of max for each participant.

Does anyone know how can I go ahead with doing it?

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

# Setting up sample data
df <- tibble(participant= rep(sprintf("A%02d",1:10),2),
             role= rep(c(rep("male",6),rep("female",4)),2),
             temp = sample(seq(36,38,by=0.1),20),
             humidity = sample(seq(50,80,by=1),20))

# Generating summary 
as_gt(df %>%
        select(-role) %>% 
        tbl_summary(by=participant,
                    missing="no",
                    statistic = list(
                      all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sd} ({max})"
                    ),
                    label= list(
                      temp ~ "Core Temperature",
                      humidity ~ "Humidity"),
                    digits = list(
                      temp ~ 1,
                      humidity ~ 0)) %>%
        add_overall() %>%
        modify_header(label= "**Parameters**",
                      all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**") %>%
        bold_labels())
```

Comment: This phrase doesn't make sense to me, "standard deviation of max for each participant." How would you do this outside of gtsummary?

Comment: Hi Daniel (wow you do reply to stackoverflow comments I'm so glad! and thanks for your awesome package!) 
- I would take the df and group by participant, get the max temperature for each participant and get the standard deviation of the max (i.e. if there are 10 participants, I would get the standard deviation of the 10 max values)

Comment: You can pass any function that accepts a numeric vector and returns a single number. It sounds like your computation is more complex in your structure as it is. You'd need to do some pre-processing to get the max first, pass a data frame that is one line per participant, and you can specify the `"{sd}"` statistics.